# Testing the function type returned from another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs

I have a function which returns another function:

```
    const returnedFunction = () => {}

    const returnFunction = () => {
        const function = returnedFunction();

        // Do stuff

        return function;
    }
```

I want to test the type of function returned from `returnFunction` is of type `returnedFunction`. Jest seems to pick it up in the response:

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "[Function returnedFunction]"
    Received: [Function returnedFunction]
```

but I can't work out how to match them up.

Comment: Is the returned function an export in its own module by any chance? If so you could mock it and expect that it is called?

Comment: @Rezaa91 But I would like to see the correct type is being returned, I'm already sort of doing that with with a spy. I've updated the question with a better example of how it's working as I'm not just executing the function and returning I do stuff between it.

Comment: In your example `returnFunction()` does not actually return a function, it calls  `returnedFunction()` which returns an empty Object and then does // some stuff and then returns that Object.

Comment: @Wodlo ah, that's a good point... Missed that, as in my actual code that function then returns another function :)

Comment: The typechecker's job in typescript is to, well, check that the types in your programs match the ones you write. Why are you writing tests to verify types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are compared by reference, so if you construct the function in your `returnedFunction` and in your tests, even if they look the same they will not be considered equal.

You should introduce some way of sharing the reference between your tests and your code. For instance,

```
// Note that sharedFn can now be used in your test for comparison
const sharedFn = () => {};
const returnedFunction = () => { return sharedFn; };

...

const received = returnFunction();
expec(received).toBe(sharedFn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `function` is a reserved key word in javascript, and variables cannot be named `function`

I am not sure what exactly you meant with

> is of type `returnedFunction`

Do you need to know which function has been called? Unless you keep references to your functions (in an object for example), or assign them unique identifiers, you can't really equal functions, event with `toString()`, which will only guarantee that the string representations (the code) of two functions are the same.

I would try:

```js
let returnedFunction = () => {};
returnedFunction.id = "returnedFunction";

const returnFunction = () => {
    const function = returnedFunction;
    // Do stuff
    return function;
}

// getting id of the returned function
returnFunction().id
```

But I am unclear on the goal of that...